# How to check user's response and allow variations on the answer string

Tags: python

I am working on a project that asks a user to type in their response to a question, and check's it for accuracy against the stored answer. Sometimes there are answers with a portion of the answer in parenthesis (). I want the user to be able to input either just the part of the answer NOT contained in parenthesis, or just the portion INSIDE the parenthesis, and have them both be counted as correct.

For example, if the answer is "Starry Night (by Vincent van Gogh)", I want the user to be able to type in either "Starry Night" or "by Vincent van Gogh" as the answer instead of the whole string.

I am not very skilled when it comes to programming, so the only thing I have been able to do so far is check the user's response for accuracy based on matching characters.

Comment: Please show your work in an [mcve].